# How to go about moving emails from outlook exchange account to Thunderbird

Tags: windows-7, windows

I no longer use outlook as my email client and use Thunderbird instead. However, a lot of my emails from my old exchange account are located in outlook. How can I transfer these emails into Thunderbird?

Comment: Extract each email into its own .eml file then drop and drag the email into Thunderbird.  There are add-ons to do this that exist.

Comment: If you can download them from the exchange server into your PC (local storage), Thunderbird will import them directly with a few clicks.

Answer (score 0):

1. Enable a gmail account in Outlook, transfer the emails onto that
   account (COPY them in the Outlook folders).
2. Then connect Thunderbird to the same gmail account and move the
   emails back to local storage.

*It was a long time ago I did this trick, so I cannot provide more details.*